# Problema no xml do managerengine

Tags: html, xml, api, xmlhttprequest, token

Olá,

```
<operation name="GET_REQUESTS">
<result>
<status>Failed</status>
<message>POST_ONLY_URL</message>
<error_code>4001</error_code>
</result>
</operation>
```

https://sdpondemand.manageengine.com/api/request?scope=sdpodapi&authtoken=mytoken&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS

Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Bem, como não foi dado nenhum contexto isso é apenas um chute... Mas a mensagem (POST_ONLY_URL) sugere que você só pode acessar a url através de um POST...

Comment: foi exatamente isso, desculpe, esqueci de dar o feedback